# Reuse ElementTree.iterparse

Tags: python, iteration, elementtree

I have two xml file one containing product information other one product description.
I'm having problem reusing `ElementTree.iterparse` multiple times and haven't found any evidence so far if it is even possible iterating over `ElementTree.iterparse` multiple times.
So far I've solved my problem by reading part of the second xml into a `dict` which is not very memory efficient keeping so much text data in memory, but at least it is fast.
My question is it is possible to iterate `ElementTree.iterparse` multiple times or extend `ElementTree` to allow multiple iteration?

## Reading product description

```
desc_iter = ElementTree.iterparse(
    desc_filename, events=('start',))
row_id = 0
desc_list = {}
for event, elem in desc_iter:
    if event == 'start' and elem.tag == 'record':
        row_id = elem.attrib['num']
    if event == 'start' and elem.tag == 'DESCRIPTION' and elem.text is not None:
        desc_list[row_id] = elem.text
    elem.clear()
```

## Using product description and iterating through product data

```
    data_iter = ElementTree.iterparse(
        data_filename, events=('start', 'end'))
    result = copy.deepcopy(self.default_result)
    result['downloader_id'] = self.downloader_id
    for event, elem in data_iter:
        if event == 'start' and elem.tag == 'record':
            pass
            ....
        if event == 'end' and elem.tag == 'record':
            print(result)
            print('='*200)
            result = copy.deepcopy(self.default_result)
            result['downloader_id'] = self.downloader_id
        elem.clear()
    del data_iter
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `iterparse` method return an [iterator](https://docs.python.org/3.7/glossary.html#term-iterator) which will by definition be closed when the end is reached.

If you want to read the data multiple times, there are only two solutions:

1. Store the data in a `list` or a `dict` (your solution so far)
2. Call the `iterparse` once again each time.

Eventually, if you seek for a specific information each time, you could use methods like [Element.find()](https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/xml.etree.elementtree.html#xml.etree.ElementTree.Element.find)

Comment: Thank you @olinox14 for the quick answer. I admit I hoped that there is a solution to make a copy/clone from the iterator object. The problem with calling `iterparse` is that when the product data xml contains e.g. thousands of rows using `iterparse` I would open thousands of times the same file. The `Element.find()` requires the second xml file be in the memory, I mean the whole xml file right? It would be nice not to store so much amount of data in the memory. Than I would stick to my solution, using `dict`. Anyhow thank you for the clarification, it helped a lot!

Comment: I think storing the data in a variable like a dict is a good solution. Yes, it it takes some memory, but it will be the most efficient, performant and readable solution...

Comment: But if you really don't want to store your data in a var, there are other methods detailed [here](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/xml.etree.elementtree.html#finding-interesting-elements) about searching elements with lxml.

Comment: I'm currently open to both ideas; later I'm going to do some tests to see how the first solution performs iterating over 75+ thousands rows; and will definitely give a shot to the second option. I admit that I think that not the memory consumption will be the bottleneck of this project but it is an another topic. Thank you once more I really appreciate your help.